# Why we use ViewTreeObserver#addOnGlobalLayoutListener()

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-view, android-viewtreeobserver

Why do we use `ViewTreeObserver`, please can anyone explain it?

In below code `creditsView` is `TextView` object. By this whole code I understand that "this is to hide some text based on condition", but only thing is why we are using `ViewTreeObserver`?

```
mainLayout.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
            int heightDiff = mainLayout.getRootView().getHeight() - mainLayout.getHeight();

            if (heightDiff > 100) {
                Utils.appLogger("MyActivity", "keyboard opened");
                creditsView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }

            if (heightDiff < 100) {
                Utils.appLogger("MyActivity", "keyboard closed");
                creditsView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If you hadn't used `ViewTreeObserver`, than `mainLayout.getRootView().getHeight()` would simply return 0px, because it  hasn't been laid out yet (see [`getWidth()` and `getHeight()` of `View` returns 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3591784/views-getwidth-and-getheight-returns-0)).

Thus, you are waiting until view is measured, laid out, and then you are fetching width/height values from it. This callback will be fired exactly when the view is going to be laid out on the screen.

Comment: @PrasanthYejje, as a newcomer, as somebody answers to your question, and you are satisfied with the answer, mark the answer as accepted.

Answer (score 11):

Don't know why but this was the first page shown to me when i searched for KOTLIN and after passsing Lamda i was unable to remove listner.

This is how i did in kotlin

```
tvLoginWith.viewTreeObserver.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(object : ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener {
        @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
        override fun onGlobalLayout() {
            tvLoginWith.viewTreeObserver.removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this)
            tvLogin.layoutParams.width = tvLoginWith.width
            tvLogin.requestLayout()
        }
    })
```

Kool way to do this  in kotlin (Reusable)
create extension like this

```
fun ViewGroup.addViewObserver(function: () -> Unit) {
    val view = this
    view.viewTreeObserver.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(object : ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener {
        override fun onGlobalLayout() {
            view.viewTreeObserver.removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this)
            function.invoke()
        }
    })
}
```

And use it from activity like this

```
listThumb.addViewObserver {
 // your code
}
```

listThumb is recyclerview in this case

Comment: Agree, with lambda we strangely cannot use and remove listener.

Comment: What if I'm using it only in xml, data-binding?

Comment: @CoolMind i guess its like how in javascript lamdas functions don't have their own this (context). lexical scopes

Comment: @AkleshSingh, yes, it sounds properly.