# Understanding getViewTreeObserver

Tags: java, android

First of all, Let me aplogize, but I didnt know where else to ask.

I want to understand the following code that can be [found here.](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rahulmmohan/SpringAnimation/master/app/src/main/java/info/overrideandroid/springanimation/MainActivity.java)

I understand all of it apart from the `getViewTreeObserver` bit:

```
movingView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
    @Override
    public void onGlobalLayout() {
        yAnimation = createSpringAnimation(movingView,SpringAnimation.Y, movingView.getY(), STIFFNESS, DAMPING_RATIO);
        xAnimation = createSpringAnimation(movingView,SpringAnimation.X, movingView.getX(), STIFFNESS, DAMPING_RATIO);
        movingView.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
    }
});
```

Why do we need this bit? The last line, removes the `OnGlobalLayoutListener` from the `movingView`, so I dont understand why we set it and then remove it.  If I take the `yAnimation` and `xAmination` lines out of this listener, and just run them on their own, the code still works fine however it doesn't return to its original X and Y.  But I dont understand why the above code allows the `createSpringAnimation`function to receive the *correct* X and Y.

Please, can someone help me understand?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewTreeObserver

Comment: Theres also another explanation here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43633485/why-we-use-viewtreeobserveraddongloballayoutlistener

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Android needs time to lay out the `View`s in your layout. If you try to read any parameter of the View straight away you normally get 0 or any default value that the framework uses before managing to calculate the correct value.
Since this operation is asynchronous you need to register a listener to be notified when the layout is ready. Then, of course, you can read the values and remove the listener because it is not necessary anymore.
Be careful though because sometimes the listener is called multiple times so before using the values and before unregistering the listener check that you actually managed to read meaningful values.

Comment: Thank you - that really helps.  So how can I check for meaningful values - I guess anything that isn't 0.0f?

Comment: yes I normally just check that the values are non-zero