# Android NestedScrollView with ConstraintLayout Layouting

Tags: android, xml, android-studio

I need some help.
I dont know what's wrong with my code.
So I have XML file like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background_bottom_sheet_radius_16"
    tools:context=".FilterActiveIpdDialog">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ic_filter_close_active_ipd"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginVertical="@dimen/medium_fit"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/medium"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_close_grey"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:ignore="ContentDescription,ImageContrastCheck" />

    <com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_filter_header"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/large"
        android:text="@string/filter"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.MaterialComponents.Headline5"
        android:textColor="@color/colorBlackGrade"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/ic_filter_close_active_ipd"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/ic_filter_close_active_ipd"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/ic_filter_close_active_ipd" />

    <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/layout_rv_filter_active_ipd"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/match_constraint"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/medium"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/medium"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/btn_filter_dialog_active_ipd"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/ic_filter_close_active_ipd">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/layout_bottom_sheet_active_ipd"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/rv_hospital"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/medium_fit"
                android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/small"
                tools:listitem="@layout/item_hospital_filter_active_ipd" />

            <View
                android:id="@+id/div_filter"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/micro"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/medium"
                android:background="@color/colorBlackGrade" />

            <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
                android:id="@+id/layout_all_ward_active_ipd"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/medium_fit"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/small"
                android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/small"
                android:paddingVertical="@dimen/small">

                <com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_filter__all_ward"
                    style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Title"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="start|center_vertical"
                    android:text="@string/all_wards"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorBlackGrade"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/text_medium" />

                <com.google.android.material.checkbox.MaterialCheckBox
                    android:id="@+id/cb_all_ward"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="end"
                    android:buttonTint="@color/colorPrimaryMid"
                    android:text=""
                    tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

            </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

            <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/rv_ward"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/medium_fit"
                android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/small"
                tools:listitem="@layout/item_ward_filter_active_ipd" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>

    <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        android:id="@+id/btn_filter_dialog_active_ipd"
        style="@style/Widget.CoreTheme.ButtonRadius"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/empty"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginHorizontal="@dimen/large"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/medium"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/medium"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/medium"
        android:text="@string/filter"
        android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
        android:textSize="@dimen/text_small"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/colorSecondaryBase"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        tools:ignore="DuplicateSpeakableTextCheck,TextContrastCheck" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

I think the problem is in the NestedScrollView.

```
<androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/layout_rv_filter_active_ipd"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/match_constraint"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/medium"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/medium"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/btn_filter_dialog_active_ipd"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/ic_filter_close_active_ipd">
```

I don't know what's wrong.
the design in Android studio shown perfectly like

[image]

but when I run the app.
just like this.

[image]

if I change the NestedScrollView height to 500dp the UI is good when using a phone with 6-inch screen, on a different phone screen it's messed up the layout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fix this problem with
set state the bottomsheet behaviour to STATE_EXPANDED.

reference:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/62958074/14863421

Answer (score 1):

Since this is a BottomSheet, I believe what is happening is that the `NestedScrollView`'s height is 0 at the beginning, and when the data arrives, the `RecyclerView` gets populated but the height is still 0.

One way to fix this is to use `fillViewport = true` in your `NestedScrollView`.

If that doesn't work you could use [ViewTreeObserver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52494270/understanding-getviewtreeobserver), so in your fragment/activity when the data arrives (I am assuming you're calling a REST API) you can populate your `RecyclerView` inside a `ViewTreeObserver` like this:

```
nestedScrollView.viewTreeObserver.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(object :
    ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener {
    override fun onGlobalLayout() {
        nestedScrollView.viewTreeObserver.removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this)
        // populate recycler view
        nestedScrollView.requestLayout()
    }
})
```

Comment: the explanation from you is so usefull, but the code is not work on me.
Thankyou Omar.
so the fix is, I set state the bottomsheet behavior to STATE_EXPANDED.