# How to get the height of an Android layout in Java?

Tags: java, android

I have a fragment and I want to know the layout height at runtime, somewhere like onStart() or onResume() or onViewStateRestored()
I am using layout.getHeight() but it returns 0 unless if I leave the app and come back to it again.
I've read that this doesn't work because it must display the layout first, and that another method is to use layout.measure() and then layout.getMeasuredHeight()
This works better, in the sense that it returns a value, but the value is a 'bit' off. For example I get 625 instead of ~2200

I guess I could cheat a bit and get the screen height and then substract the action bar and nav bar, but this might not work well if the window is not full screen.

So any idea on how I can get the proper layout height?

Comment: You are basically answering your own question. You need the correct event to broadcast this information from. The events you mentioned (`onStart`, `onResume`, etc.) happen before the view is fully rendered. This is why when you leave and come back, you can get the information you want from the `onViewStateRestored` and/or from `onResume`. You need to find out about all of the UI events in Android and find one that fires when the application is loaded, or a view finish rendering. I am no Android expert, but I assume there is an event for those activities.

Comment: I am no Android expert either :) I tried all the events I could think of, but couldn't find one. That doesn't mean there isn't one, just that I didn't find it. Also, I thought there might be some other way, similar to the getMeasuredHeight() (or maybe some way to convert it from what getMeasuredHeight() gives me to actual pixels)?

Comment: Maybe you can find information [here](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/vitals/launch-time)?

Comment: It's possible to get from a layout after it's loaded using `ViewTreeObserver`. You can find some code for this here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43633485/why-we-use-viewtreeobserveraddongloballayoutlistener.

Comment: Great, the viewitreeobserver really helped me. I put it in onStart() and when it fires it calls my function. The problem is that it fires a lot, I have to now find a way how to remove itself after firing for the first time :) (I am not really a Java guy).

Comment: Ok, just had to add layout.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this); at the end and it worked.  
Alias Cartellano, post it as an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: @Radu you can also post your own answer. Of course, you will need to provide sufficient code to be helpful to others. I also suggest improving your question to show the minimal, reproducible code.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, thanks to the help from Alias Cartellano I managed to solve it.
This is the code, in case anyone else finds it useful:

```
    @Override
    public void onViewStateRestored(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewStateRestored(savedInstanceState);
        Log.e(TAG, "On view state restored called...");

        final RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.myRelativeLayout);

        layout.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
            @Override
            public void onGlobalLayout() {
                int height = layout.getHeight();
                place_camera_buttons(height);
                layout.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
            }
        });

    }
```